# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/application.js")

Tags: javascript, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

I'm currently working on a Rails 5.2 application with Vue installed in it via webpacker. However, I have not done any styling. I'm just setting the authentication. When I go to `users/sign_out` I get the following error.

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/javascripts/application.js"):

I do have a file in `/javascripts/application.js` which had the following code:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require_tree .
```

Not sure what the issue is here.

```
<head>
    <title>ArtsySpace</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  </head>
```

in `environments/development.rb/`

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Verifies that versions and hashed value of the package contents in the project's package.json
  config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = true
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  config.assets.debug = false
  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  # Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Highlight code that triggered database queries in logs.
  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

  config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = false


  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is old but for anyone coming across this issue, you need to change:
`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`
to
`<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>`

Comment: Can you explain what this changes? 
I'm getting `undefined method 'javascript_pack_tag'` after changing this

Comment: @Smartens if you've upgraded to Rails 6 this would "activate" your webpack installation and instruct rails to use webpack instead of asset pipeline

Comment: I think there is a bug in Rails 7 and I am not using packs, but did change to `javascript_pack_tag` and then back to `javascript_include_tag` as it should be and got rid of the error. This has happened twice over the last couple of months. Maybe the bug is in Git which picks up something old, but in any case the flip-flop-flip works.

Comment: @Greg It worked! It's annoying though. Edit: Deletion of asset builds also helps: `rm -rf app/assets/builds/*`